# How can I match & modify an array of dictionaries?

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm currently stuck trying to match & modify two dictionaries against each other. At a high level, I have an array of dictionaries of potential answer_ids to each question:

```
[{'2194241222': 'Not at all likely - 0',
  '2194241223': '1',
  '2194241224': '2',
  '2194241391': '3',
  '2194241392': '4',
  '2194241393': '5',
  '2194241394': '6',
  '2194241395': '7',
  '2194241396': '8',
  '2194241397': '9',
  '2194241398': 'Extremely likely - 10'},
 {'2194241407': 'Very satisfied',
  '2194241408': 'Somewhat satisfied',
  '2194241409': 'Neither satisfied nor dissatisfied',
  '2194241410': 'Somewhat dissatisfied',
  '2194241411': 'Very dissatisfied'},
 {'2194241444': 'Extremely well',
  '2194241445': 'Very well',
  '2194241446': 'Somewhat well',
  '2194241447': 'Not so well',
  '2194241448': 'Not at all well'}
```

And an array of answers from actual responses:

```
{'answers': [{'choice_id': '2194241397', 'row_id': '2194241221'}],
  'id': '331799110'},
 {'answers': [{'choice_id': '2194241408'}], 'id': '331799114'},
 {'answers': [{'choice_id': '2194241422'}], 'id': '331799115'},
 {'answers': [{'choice_id': '2194241445'}], 'id': '331799117'},
 {'answers': [{'choice_id': '2194241457'}], 'id': '331799122'},
 {'answers': [{'choice_id': '2194241466'}], 'id': '331799126'},
 {'answers': [{'choice_id': '2194241500'}], 'id': '331799128'},
 {'answers': [{'choice_id': '2194241535'}], 'id': '331799130'},
 {'answers': [{'choice_id': '2194241555'}], 'id': '331799132'}
```

How can I replace the `choice_id` number with the value of the `answer_id` dictionary?

All `answer_id` numbers are unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just do something like this:

```
# responseL - The array in the first snippet
# answerL - The array in the second snippet
# Convert responseL to a dictionary
responseD = { k: v for resp_typeD in responseL for k, v in resp_typeD.items() }

for answerD in answerL:
    for questionD in answerD['answers']:
        questionD['choice_id'] = responseD.get(questionD['choice_id'], "UNKNOWN")
```

Comment: Wow this is amazing. This worked perfectly, thank you! I don't really understand what's happening, but it was perfect. Thanks again!